# Add FormXobject content from resources to content stream using PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have FormXobject under my page1->Resource -> Xobjects-> Fm0, Fm1, Fm2..

So it is not direct content stream which is not available under contents->contentstream.  So I want to move the content stream of from Fm0->Contentstream to page1-> contents-> contentstream.

When we moved content stream like this we parallelly we have to transfer or copy Fm0 related Resources to page level resource.

[image: As shown here.]

1.Content stream need to copy under page level contents.

2.Color space objects need to copy under page1->Resource->Colorspace.

3.ExtGState objects need to copy under page1->Resource->ExtGState.

4.properties need to copy under page1->Resource (here need to create that entirely)

I tried some code

```
private static PDDocument parseFormXobject(PDDocument document, Integer pg_ind) throws IOException {
List<Object> tokens1 = (List<Object>) (getTokens(document, pg_ind)).get(pg_ind);
PDStream newContents = new PDStream(document);
OutputStream out = newContents.createOutputStream(COSName.FLATE_DECODE);
ContentStreamWriter writer = new ContentStreamWriter(out);

PDPage pageinner = document.getPage(pg_ind);
PDResources resources = pageinner.getResources();
PDResources new_resources = new PDResources();
new_resources = resources;

COSDictionary fntdict = new COSDictionary();
COSDictionary imgdict = new COSDictionary();
COSDictionary extgsdict = new COSDictionary();
COSDictionary colordict = new COSDictionary();
COSDictionary pattern = new COSDictionary();
int img_count = 0;
for (COSName xObjectName : resources.getXObjectNames()) {
    PDXObject xObject = resources.getXObject(xObjectName);
    if (xObject instanceof PDFormXObject
        && tokens1.toString().contains(xObjectName.toString()) ) {
        PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(((PDFormXObject) xObject).getContentStream());
        parser.parse();
        List<Object>  tokens3 = parser.getTokens();
        int ind =0;
        //isTextContains will check is there any Tj operators or there or not
        if (isTextContains(tokens3)){
            for (COSName colorname :((PDFormXObject) xObject).getResources().getColorSpaceNames())
            {
                COSName new_name = COSName.getPDFName(colorname.getName());
                PDColorSpace pdcolor = ((PDFormXObject) xObject).getResources().getColorSpace(colorname);
                colordict.setItem(new_name,pdcolor);
            }
            for (COSName fontName :((PDFormXObject) xObject).getResources().getFontNames() )
            {
                COSName new_name = COSName.getPDFName(fontName.getName());
                PDFont font =((PDFormXObject) xObject).getResources().getFont(fontName);
                font.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.NAME, new_name);
                fntdict.setItem(new_name,font);
            }
            for (COSName ExtGSName :((PDFormXObject) xObject).getResources().getExtGStateNames() )
            {
                COSName new_name = COSName.getPDFName(ExtGSName.getName());
                PDExtendedGraphicsState ExtGState =((PDFormXObject) xObject).getResources().getExtGState(ExtGSName);
                ExtGState.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.NAME, new_name);
                extgsdict.setItem(new_name,ExtGState);
            }
            imgdict.setItem(xObjectName, xObject);
            for (COSName Imgname :((PDFormXObject) xObject).getResources().getXObjectNames() )
            {
                COSName new_name = COSName.getPDFName(Imgname.getName());
                xObject.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.NAME, new_name);
                PDXObject img =((PDFormXObject) xObject).getResources().getXObject(Imgname);
                imgdict.setItem(new_name, img);
            }
            for (COSName paternname :((PDFormXObject) xObject).getResources().getPatternNames() )
            {
                COSName new_name = COSName.getPDFName(paternname.getName());
                PDAbstractPattern pat = ((PDFormXObject) xObject).getResources().getPattern(paternname);
                pat.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.NAME, new_name);
                pattern.setItem(new_name,pat);
            }
            for (int k=0; k< tokens1.size(); k++) {
                if ( ((tokens1.get(k) instanceof Operator) && ((Operator)tokens1.get(k)).getName().toString().equals("Do"))
                        && ((COSName)tokens1.get(k-1)).getName().toString().equals(xObjectName.getName().toString()) ) {
                    tokens1.remove(k-1);
                    tokens1.remove(k-1);
                    tokens1.add(k-1, Operator.getOperator("q"));
                    if(((PDFormXObject) xObject).getMatrix() != null) {
                        tokens1.add(k, new COSFloat(((PDFormXObject) xObject).getMatrix().getScaleX()));
                        tokens1.add(k + 1, new COSFloat(((PDFormXObject) xObject).getMatrix().getShearY()));
                        tokens1.add(k + 2, new COSFloat(((PDFormXObject) xObject).getMatrix().getShearX()));
                        tokens1.add(k + 3, new COSFloat(((PDFormXObject) xObject).getMatrix().getScaleY()));
                        tokens1.add(k + 4, new COSFloat(((PDFormXObject) xObject).getMatrix().getTranslateX()));
                        tokens1.add(k + 5, new COSFloat(((PDFormXObject) xObject).getMatrix().getTranslateY()));
                        tokens1.add(k + 6, Operator.getOperator("cm"));
                        tokens1.add(k+7, Operator.getOperator("Q"));
                        ind =k+7;
                    }else{
                        tokens1.add(k, Operator.getOperator("Q"));
                        ind =k;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

            for (int k=0; k< tokens3.size(); k++) {
                if ( (tokens3.size() > k+1) && (tokens3.get(k+1) instanceof Operator) && (((Operator)tokens3.get(k+1)).getName().toString().equals("Do")
                        || ((Operator)tokens3.get(k+1)).getName().toString().equals("gs")
                        || ((Operator)tokens3.get(k+1)).getName().toString().equals("cs")
                        || ((Operator)tokens3.get(k+1)).getName().toString().equals("CS")) ) {
                    COSName new_name = COSName.getPDFName( ((COSName) tokens3.get(k)).getName() );
                    tokens1.add(ind+k, new_name );
                }else if ( (tokens3.size() > k+2) && (tokens3.get(k+2) instanceof Operator)
                        && ((Operator)tokens3.get(k+2)).getName().toString().equals("Tf") ) {
                    COSName new_name = COSName.getPDFName( ((COSName) tokens3.get(k)).getName() );
                    tokens1.add(ind+k, new_name );
                }
                else
                    tokens1.add(ind+k,tokens3.get(k));
            }


            img_count +=1;
        }else {
            imgdict.setItem(xObjectName, xObject);
            img_count +=1;
        }
    }else
        imgdict.setItem(xObjectName, xObject);
}
for (COSName fontName :new_resources.getFontNames() )
{
    PDFont font =new_resources.getFont(fontName);
    fntdict.setItem(fontName,font);
}
for (COSName ExtGSName :new_resources.getExtGStateNames() )
{
    PDExtendedGraphicsState extg =new_resources.getExtGState(ExtGSName);
    extgsdict.setItem(ExtGSName,extg);
}
for (COSName colorname :new_resources.getColorSpaceNames() )
{
    PDColorSpace color =new_resources.getColorSpace(colorname);
    colordict.setItem(colorname,color);
}
for (COSName patern :new_resources.getPatternNames() )
{
    PDAbstractPattern pat =new_resources.getPattern(patern);
    pattern.setItem(patern,pat);
}

resources.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.EXT_G_STATE,extgsdict);
resources.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.FONT,fntdict);
resources.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.XOBJECT,imgdict);
resources.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.COLORSPACE, colordict);
resources.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.PATTERN, pattern);

writer.writeTokens(tokens1);
out.close();
document.getPage(pg_ind).setContents(newContents);
document.getPage(pg_ind).setResources(resources);
return document;
}

private static JSONObject getTokens(PDDocument oldDocument, Integer pageIndex) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto- it will return the tokens of pdf
    JSONObject oldDocumentTokens = new JSONObject();
    PDPage pg = oldDocument.getPage(pageIndex);
    PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(pg);
    parser.parse();
    List<Object> tokens = PDFUtils.removeTokens(parser.getTokens());
    oldDocumentTokens.put(pageIndex, tokens);
    return oldDocumentTokens;
}

private static boolean isTextContains(List<Object> tokens3) {
    for (int k=0; k< tokens3.size(); k++) {
        if (tokens3.get(k) instanceof Operator) {
            Operator op = (Operator) tokens3.get(k);
            if(op.getName().equals("BT"))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But I am unable to get Exact Page graphics. I am losing something.

[input pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lT4pwGAk4I6vaekTHhWnx_hngcKCm0DK/view?usp=sharing)

[output pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RikX4E5WRN6fq_0Cv4PBYaMabJuHONq9/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You completely ignore that a XObject can be more than merely a macro-like set of instructions for re-use: XObjects can also define **transparency groups** which makes a difference for how transparency is interpreted. Your **Fm0** is such a transparency group. If you simply move the XObject instructions into the page content stream, you can count on the results looking different where non-trivial transparency effects are used.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't see you enclosing the inserted instructions in a save-graphics-state/restore-graphics-state envelope. Also you appear to assume that an XObject is used exactly once; this need not be the case.

Comment: can you please help me to get insert save-graphics-state/restore-graphics-state envelope properly. I have less knowledge on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues, some in details, some in the concept.

#### Wrapping in a save-graphics-state/restore-graphics-state envelope

When you draw an XObject, graphics state changes in that XObject don't change your current graphics state. To make sure this still is true after you copied the XObject instructions into your page content stream, you have to wrap that block into a save-graphics-state/restore-graphics-state envelope (**q** ... **Q**). You can do that by adding these two lines

```java
tokens1.add(ind++, Operator.getOperator("q"));
tokens1.add(ind, Operator.getOperator("Q"));
```

right before your instruction copying loop

```java
for (int k=0; k< tokens3.size(); k++) {
    ...
}
```

#### Coordinate system

You assume the coordinate system in the XObject equals that of the page. It doesn't necessarily. XObjects may have a **Matrix** entry denoting the transformation to apply.

#### Boundary box

You don't limit the area of what is drawn by the XObject instructions. But XObjects have a **BBox** entry denoting the box to clip the outputs to.

#### Optional content

XObjects may also have an **OC** entry denoting their optional content membership. Such a membership needs to be transformed into an equivalent optional content tagging.

#### Marked content, structure tree

XObjects can also refer to the structural parent tree via their **StructParent** or **StructParents** entry. To keep structural integrity of the document, you may have to considerably update the structure tree.

#### Grouping

XObjects may contain a **Group** entry indicating that its content shall be treated as a group. In particular in case of Transparency Groups this results in a different behavior of transparency related features than for the same instructions copied into the page content.

Unless you completely analyze the effects of each bit of content drawn with some transparency and from case to case rewrite the instructions drawing it, copying the instructions from the XObject to the page content stream will result in substantial differences in the displayed content.

#### Usage

Your code assumes that a XObject is used exactly once in the page content streams. This need not be the case, it can also be used more often or not at all.

---

#### References

In a comment you asked for references. Actually it's all in the PDF specification ISO 32000, already in the publicly available ISO 32000-1:

> ### 8.10 Form XObjects
>
> A *form XObject* is a PDF content stream that is a self-contained description of any sequence of graphics objects (including path objects, text objects, and sampled images). A form XObject may be painted multiple times—either on several pages or at several locations on the same page—and produces the same results each time, subject only to the graphics state at the time it is invoked.

Thus, any number of usages on a given page is possible

> When the **Do** operator is applied to a form XObject, a conforming reader shall perform the following tasks:
>
> a) Saves the current graphics state, as if by invoking the **q** operator (see 8.4.4, "Graphics State Operators")
>
> b) Concatenates the matrix from the form dictionary’s **Matrix** entry with the current transformation matrix (CTM)
>
> c) Clips according to the form dictionary’s **BBox** entry
>
> d) Paints the graphics objects specified in the form’s content stream
>
> e) Restores the saved graphics state, as if by invoking the **Q** operator (see 8.4.4, "Graphics State Operators")

When copying into the page content stream, therefore, you should equivalently use a **q**/**Q** envelope and respect the **Matrix** and **BBox** entries.

> ### 8.11.3.3 Optional Content in XObjects and Annotations
>
> In addition to marked content within content streams, form XObjects and image XObjects (see 8.8, "External Objects") and annotations (see 12.5, "Annotations") may contain an **OC** entry, which shall be an optional content group or an optional content membership dictionary.
>
> A form or image XObject's visibility shall be determined by the state of the group or those of the groups referenced by the membership dictionary in conjunction with its **P** (or **VE**) entry, along with the current visibility state in the context in which the XObject is invoked (that is, whether objects are visible in the contents stream at the place where the **Do** operation occurred).

Thus, respect this optional content information when copying to the page content.

> ### 11.6.6 Transparency Group XObjects
>
> A transparency group is represented in PDF as a special type of group XObject (see “Group XObjects”) called a *transparency group XObject*. A group XObject is in turn a type of form XObject, distinguished by the presence of a **Group** entry in its form dictionary (see “Form Dictionaries”). The value of this entry is a subsidiary *group attributes dictionary* defining the properties of the group. The format and meaning of the dictionary’s contents shall be determined by its *group subtype*, which is specified by the dictionary’s **S** entry. The entries for a transparency group (subtype **Transparency**) are shown in Table 147.
>
> ...
>
> ### Annex L
>
> [image: figures L.16 and L.17]

So copying from transparency groups may change the appearance substantially.

> ### 14.7.4.3 PDF Objects as Content Items
>
> When a structure element’s content includes an entire PDF object, such as an XObject or an annotation, that is associated with a page but not directly included in the page’s content stream, the object shall be identified in the structure element’s **K** entry by an *object reference dictionary* (see Table 325).
>
> ...
>
> ### 14.7.4.4 Finding Structure Elements from Content Items
>
> ...
>
> To locate the relevant parent tree entry, each object or content stream that is represented in the tree shall contain a special dictionary entry, **StructParent** or **StructParents** (see Table 326). Depending on the type of content item, this entry may appear in the page object of a page containing marked-content sequences, in the stream dictionary of a form or image XObject, in an annotation dictionary, or in any other type of object dictionary that is included as a content item in a structure element.

This and more information from the same chapter should indicate clearly that structure information after copying from XObject to page content must be overhauled.

Comment: And can you please paste the link where did you read this content. That helps me to better understand.

Comment: Well, it's all from the specification, ISO 32000-1. I can add references to specific sections later.

Comment: As I saw that Group, matrix and BBox are out of the resource properties and unique for entire page I guess. How can I set those properties again for page level?

Comment: You cannot transport the group properties along into the page because the group properties (among other things) define how the contents of the group XObject interact transparency-wise with the page content, so after copying into the page (some of) the group properties wouldn't mean the same anymore. And as far as copying the others into the page group properties is concerned, different group XObjects may have contradictory properties, so when merging them all into the page contents, you'd have to chose in favor of some and against other properties of former group XObjects.

Comment: As far as matrix and BBox are concerned, simply do as indicated in the quote of 8.10 Form XObjects: *Concatenate the matrix from the form dictionary’s Matrix entry with the current transformation matrix* by means of a **cm** instruction and *Clip according to the form dictionary’s BBox entry* by creating a rectangle path using the BBox coordinates using a **re** instruction, clip using a **W** instruction, and release the path using a **n** instruction.

Comment: I am adding the each point related snippet code above please correct me, If am wrongly doing. (please edit the answer)

Answer (score 0):

**This is just snippet code for above MKL Answer. I am trying to give snippet  code for that**

**Wrapping in a save-graphics-state/restore-graphics-state envelope**

When you draw an XObject, graphics state changes in that XObject don't change your current graphics state. To make sure this still is true after you copied the XObject instructions into your page content stream, you have to wrap that block into a save-graphics-state/restore-graphics-state envelope (q ... Q). You can do that by adding these two lines

```
tokens1.add(ind++, Operator.getOperator("q"));
tokens1.add(ind, Operator.getOperator("Q"));
```

right before your instruction copying loop

```
for (int k=0; k< tokens3.size(); k++) {
    ...
}
```

**Coordinate system:**

You assume the coordinate system in the XObject equals that of the page. It doesn't necessarily. XObjects may have a **Matrix** entry denoting the transformation to apply.

```
tokens1.add(k-1, Operator.getOperator("q"));
if(((PDFormXObject) xObject).getMatrix() != null) {
    tokens1.add(k, new COSFloat(((PDFormXObject) xObject).getMatrix().getScaleX()));
    tokens1.add(k + 1, new COSFloat(((PDFormXObject) xObject).getMatrix().getShearY()));
    tokens1.add(k + 2, new COSFloat(((PDFormXObject) xObject).getMatrix().getShearX()));
    tokens1.add(k + 3, new COSFloat(((PDFormXObject) xObject).getMatrix().getScaleY()));
    tokens1.add(k + 4, new COSFloat(((PDFormXObject) xObject).getMatrix().getTranslateX()));
    tokens1.add(k + 5, new COSFloat(((PDFormXObject) xObject).getMatrix().getTranslateY()));
    tokens1.add(k + 6, Operator.getOperator("cm"));
    tokens1.add(k+7, Operator.getOperator("Q"));
    ind =k+7;
}
```

**Boundary box:**

You don't limit the area of what is drawn by the XObject instructions. But XObjects have a **BBox** entry denoting the box to clip the outputs to.

```
if ((PDFormXObject) xObject).getBBox()!= null){
    //How can I add this bbox property? is it 're'?
    tokens1.add(k, new COSFloat(((PDFormXObject) xObject).getBBox().getLowerLeftX()));
    tokens1.add(k+1, new COSFloat(((PDFormXObject) xObject).getBBox().getLowerLeftY()));
    tokens1.add(k+2, new COSFloat(((PDFormXObject) xObject).getBBox().getWidth()));
    tokens1.add(k+3, new COSFloat(((PDFormXObject) xObject).getBBox().getHeight()));
    tokens1.add(k+4, Operator.getOperator("re"));
    tokens1.add(k+5, Operator.getOperator("W"));
    tokens1.add(k+6, Operator.getOperator("n"));
}
```

**Optional content**

XObjects may also have an **OC** entry denoting their optional content membership. Such a membership needs to be transformed into an equivalent optional content tagging.

```
//How can I get this oc property from xobject and how can I use it?
```

**Marked content, structure tree**

```
//For now there is no any marked content. Assume every pdf is not Tagged.
```

**Grouping**

XObjects may contain a **Group** entry indicating that its content shall be treated as a group. In particular in case of Transparency Groups this results in a different behavior of transparency related features than for the same instructions copied into the page content.

Unless you completely analyze the effects of each bit of content drawn with some transparency and from case to case rewrite the instructions drawing it, copying the instructions from the XObject to the page content stream will result in substantial differences in the displayed content.

```
if ((PDFormXObject) xObject).getGroup() != null
    //if this is not null how to use this?
```

**Usage**

Your code assumes that a XObject is used exactly once in the page content streams. This need not be the case, it can also be used **more often** or not at all.

```
//For this I will iterate my main content stream and replace all formxobject's.
```

**References**

I am adding snippet to copy all references.

Reading references

```
for (COSName colorname :((PDFormXObject) xObject).getResources().getColorSpaceNames())
{
    COSName new_name = COSName.getPDFName(colorname.getName());
    PDColorSpace pdcolor = ((PDFormXObject) xObject).getResources().getColorSpace(colorname);
    colordict.setItem(new_name,pdcolor);
}
for (COSName propertyName :((PDFormXObject) xObject).getResources().getPropertiesNames())
{
    COSName new_name = COSName.getPDFName(propertyName.getName()+"_Fm"+img_count);
    PDPropertyList property =((PDFormXObject) xObject).getResources().getProperties(propertyName);
    property.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.NAME, new_name);
    propertiesdict.setItem(new_name,property);
}
for (COSName shadeName :((PDFormXObject) xObject).getResources().getShadingNames() )
{
    COSName new_name = COSName.getPDFName(shadeName.getName()+"_Fm"+img_count);
    PDShading shade =((PDFormXObject) xObject).getResources().getShading(shadeName);
    shade.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.NAME, new_name);
    fntdict.setItem(new_name,shade);
}
for (COSName fontName :((PDFormXObject) xObject).getResources().getFontNames() )
{
    COSName new_name = COSName.getPDFName(fontName.getName());
    PDFont font =((PDFormXObject) xObject).getResources().getFont(fontName);
    font.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.NAME, new_name);
    fntdict.setItem(new_name,font);
}
for (COSName ExtGSName :((PDFormXObject) xObject).getResources().getExtGStateNames() )
{
    COSName new_name = COSName.getPDFName(ExtGSName.getName());
    PDExtendedGraphicsState ExtGState =((PDFormXObject) xObject).getResources().getExtGState(ExtGSName);
    ExtGState.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.NAME, new_name);
    extgsdict.setItem(new_name,ExtGState);
}
imgdict.setItem(xObjectName, xObject);
for (COSName Imgname :((PDFormXObject) xObject).getResources().getXObjectNames() )
{
    COSName new_name = COSName.getPDFName(Imgname.getName());
    xObject.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.NAME, new_name);
    PDXObject img =((PDFormXObject) xObject).getResources().getXObject(Imgname);
    imgdict.setItem(new_name, img);
}
for (COSName paternname :((PDFormXObject) xObject).getResources().getPatternNames() )
{
    COSName new_name = COSName.getPDFName(paternname.getName());
    PDAbstractPattern pat = ((PDFormXObject) xObject).getResources().getPattern(paternname);
    pat.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.NAME, new_name);
    pattern.setItem(new_name,pat);
}
//Later I am placing in place

for (COSName fontName :new_resources.getFontNames() )
{
    PDFont font =new_resources.getFont(fontName);
    fntdict.setItem(fontName,font);
}
for (COSName ExtGSName :new_resources.getExtGStateNames() )
{
    PDExtendedGraphicsState extg =new_resources.getExtGState(ExtGSName);
    extgsdict.setItem(ExtGSName,extg);
}
for (COSName colorname :new_resources.getColorSpaceNames() )
{
    PDColorSpace color =new_resources.getColorSpace(colorname);
    colordict.setItem(colorname,color);
}
for (COSName patern :new_resources.getPatternNames() )
{
    PDAbstractPattern pat =new_resources.getPattern(patern);
    pattern.setItem(patern,pat);
}

resources.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.EXT_G_STATE,extgsdict);
resources.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.FONT,fntdict);
resources.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.XOBJECT,imgdict);
resources.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.COLORSPACE, colordict);
resources.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.PATTERN, pattern);
resources.getCOSObject().setItem(COSName.PROPERTIES, propertiesdict);
//what about shading How can I add here

writer.writeTokens(tokens1);
out.close();
document.getPage(pg_ind).setContents(newContents);
document.getPage(pg_ind).setResources(resources);
```

@mkl please correct me here to give complete solution. I will try hard to make this work Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"//How can I add this bbox property? is it 're'?"* - By creating a rectangle path using the BBox coordinates using a **re** instruction, clipping using a **W** instruction, and releasing the path using a **n** instruction.

Comment: *"//How can I get this oc property from xobject and how can I use it?"* - See ISO 32000-1, section 8.11.3.3 "Optional Content in XObjects and Annotations" - simply retrieve the **OC** entry from the form XObject - and section 8.11.3.2 Optional Content in Content Streams - wrap your flattened XObjects in `/OC /XXX BDC` and `EMC`; don't forget to add the optional content group to the page resources if its not already there.

Comment: Groups *"//if this is not null how to use this?"* - You will lose that information without an XObject for the group. This may result in considerable differences in appearance.

Comment: The **re** instruction has width and height as third and fourth parameter, not the coordinates of the diagonally opposed corner.

Comment: @mkl can you please help me here to finish this answer. That can help me a lot.