# While replacing formXobjects in to content stream I am loosing Font size?

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

This question may further discussion to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66274818/add-formxobject-content-from-resources-to-content-stream-using-pdfbox).

My initial formXobject is like below.

[image]

And it looks visually

[image]

After I try to replace the "/Meta98 Do " with Xobject content stream it looks like this.

[image]

The content Stream for this new file you can check [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bdeckCmjI08-du3ow9iDG3Zx1E1aegv_/view?usp=sharing).

Before changing file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yfbwA658-FfiDUAOABDdrXZDn9KB5UFL/view?usp=sharing)

I think I am losing the Tf properties. How to replace the formxobject contents without loosing font size?

Comment: Unfortunately you don't share the file before your changes, so it is not clear what you forgot. I would assume you ignored the XObject **Matrix** entry which already was mentioned in the question you refer to at the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You forgot to take the XObject **Matrix** into account.*

In the original PDF a form XObject is used on your page:

```cos
q
0.25 0 0 0.42986 189.16 132.44 cm
/Meta98 Do
Q
```

and you simply replaced the `/Meta98 Do` by the contents from XObject (enveloped in **q**..**Q** and with tags):

```cos
q
0.25 0 0 0.42986 189.16 132.44 cm
/Formula <</MCID  74  >> BDC
/F3_Fm0 11.04 Tf
q
0.51317 w 
...
[(X)  ]TJ
EMC
ET
Q
Q
```

What you forgot, though, is taking the **Matrix** entry of the form XObject into account:

```
55 0 obj
<</BBox[0 0 18.425 31.89]/Filter/FlateDecode/Length 158/Matrix[3.9077 0 0 2.2578 0 0]/Resources<</Font<</F3 62 0 R/F4 65 0 R>>>>/Subtype/Form/Type/XObject>>stream
...
```

This matrix has to applied here, too:

```
q
0.25 0 0 0.42986 189.16 132.44 cm
% concatenate the former XObject Matrix:
3.9077 0 0 2.2578 0 0 cm
/Formula <</MCID  74  >> BDC
/F3_Fm0 11.04 Tf
q
0.51317 w 
...
[(X)  ]TJ
EMC
ET
Q
Q
```

Comment: I tried one of the pdf which I am trying to flatten it. But while pasting content stream from Fm0 to main content stream for some reason its losing "TL" object. And the pdf also weird can you please check. 
My tokens before saving https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dMsZZkhgOaO4h_t6f1rZtKKi6Km5WGNW/view?usp=sharing  
File url https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M2YokgopRAE4Ad0YM5lcXpzdsL78Un7a/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @fascinatingcoder *"I tried one of the pdf which I am trying to flatten it. But while pasting content stream from Fm0 to main content stream for some reason its losing "TL" object. And the pdf also weird can you please check..."* - Without enough code to reproduce the issue and the original input, I can hardly help. And what do you mean when you say that the PDF is weird?

Comment: I am sharing the before and after formextract  pdf's please see the text how is it showing. you will understand what the problem. It's not the pdf issue for some reason the "writeTokens" method skipping the "TL" operator.(I am thinking that's the reason why the text is showing weird. ) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dMsZZkhgOaO4h_t6f1rZtKKi6Km5WGNW/view?usp=sharing) 
before formxobject extract
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NtHHiU2auaYV9f37uXP38mZYRT_uaE9s/view?usp=sharing
after formxobject extract
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M2YokgopRAE4Ad0YM5lcXpzdsL78Un7a/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The code which I am using is updated here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66274818/add-formxobject-content-from-resources-to-content-stream-using-pdfbox)

Comment: And this(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ldYxlj3V2mXfaqvr4LW6V9DB8uNxEarq/view?usp=sharing) pdf the text I am able to show it but the font size is messing up once I flattened.  after flatten  pdf (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aez7b2kLxt08k3Ps3NWf4xl1_G3zPwQM/view?usp=sharing) I missing something. I need some generic solution to flatten. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We will complete this solution here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66274818/add-formxobject-content-from-resources-to-content-stream-using-pdfbox/73074625#73074625)

Comment: @fascinatingcoder *"The code which I am using is updated here"* - there the methods `isTextContains` and `getTokens` are missing.

Comment: @fascinatingcoder Other than that, you don't rename the fonts in the form XObject anymore. That causes the issues in the "Get Your BEST START" box. Actually you don't rename any resources anymore. Thus, many more problems are bound to pop up.

Comment: There are some use cases, where I saw that under pdf page>resources> Font> "Fm0",  same font name but different style of text I found under FormXobject  Fm0>Resources>Font>Fm0. This case while I am adding FormXobject font under page resources I am renaming it to make unique font names along with content stream.  what is the correct way to handle this?

Comment: You have to rename both in the resources and the instructions. But you don't do so yet, at least according to the code you shared adjectives the example file we're discussing.

Comment: Actually I explained above comment use case in this pdf only happened. After renaming properly it worked well, the "T1_0" to "T1_0_Fm0".  please check below file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HYzxProrcCig3l4fTV_oFqnmlb6xSOs8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok, Simply appending the form name does not _guarantee_ unique names, though - that name may also be already in use. (It's unlikely but possible.) That being said, I still cannot reproduce your issue due to the missing methods mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

The Tf properties are fine.
This section in your page content displays the fraction:

```
q
0.25 0 0 0.42986 189.16 132.44 cm
/Formula <</MCID  74  >> BDC
/F3_Fm0 11.04 Tf
q
0.51317 w
0 G
1 j
2.0282 15.322 m
15.493 15.322 l
S
BT
/F3_Fm0 7.2577 Tf
1 0 0 1 8.8216 2.517 Tm
0 g
[(m)  ]TJ
EMC
/Artifact <<>> BDC
ET
BT
1 0 0 1 11.168 20.038 Tm
EMC
/Formula <</MCID  75  >> BDC
[(p)  ]TJ
EMC
/Artifact <<>> BDC
ET
BT
/F4_Fm0 12.414 Tf
1 0 0 1 2.4192 2.517 Tm
EMC
/Formula <</MCID  76  >> BDC
[(Y)  ]TJ
EMC
/Artifact <<>> BDC
ET
BT
1 0 0 1 3.7877 20.038 Tm
EMC
/Formula <</MCID  77  >> BDC
[(X)  ]TJ
EMC
ET
Q
Q
```

The transform at the top causes your fraction to be displayed smaller:

```
0.25 0 0 0.42986 189.16 132.44 cm
```

Replacing it with

```
1 0 0 1 189.16 132.44 cm
```

almost fixes the problem so you have to check how the transform is computed.