# Understanding more about form xobjects in PDF?

Tags: pdf, itext, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I have a [PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XAXIexvwm555rxZjgR0r2tFC3MJWp_mW/view?usp=sharing) which contains form Xobject's in it. Each and every form xobject contains a full page (duplication and hidden) content in it. But for user only showing(on page screen) one image remaining all are hidden. I f I am trying to [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66274818/add-formxobject-content-from-resources-to-content-stream-using-pdfbox) it the duplication content also flattening and showing like below image.

[image: After Flatten looks like]

So to solve this problem we have to flatten only the visible content(Even I don't know which content is visible to user screen?) not entire form xobject. Is that will solve the problem. Or is there any way to solve this problem programmatically?

Comment: You can, before flattening, enclose the `/XObject Do` instructions in **q**..**Q** and add a clipping part definition right before that instruction to clip away everything outside the XObject bounding box.

Comment: @mkl enclosing with q and Q ok. But clip part definition how we can add? what is it exactly. Is it same in all the pdf. what might be the edge cases. Can you please give some example

Comment: I am wondering that how it is hiding content from Formxobject "Im44". It's not showing entire Im44 content stream only showing some part of the content stream. How would we know that?

Comment: Concerning the clip path, simply do as indicated in the quote of 8.10 Form XObjects: *Concatenate the matrix from the form dictionary’s Matrix entry with the current transformation matrix* by means of a **cm** instruction and *Clip according to the form dictionary’s BBox entry* by creating a rectangle path using the BBox coordinates using a **re** instruction, clip using a **W** instruction, and release the path using a **n** instruction. [cf my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66274818/add-formxobject-content-from-resources-to-content-stream-using-pdfbox#comment117278375_66280851)

Comment: Hi @mkl, Thanks for hint. I am able to show only the image from entire Formxobject. Remaining is hiding. But [here][1] you can see the text is duplicating. May I know the reason? And in which case I should add the 're', 'W' and 'n'? Usually I show entire formxobject content stream. But in this pdf I should use 're'. why?


  [1]: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zd4E0SZemiRbb5ASsynV0G01f6GoAfzH/view?usp=sharing